# How to change the layout of a window on changing its size (tkinter, python)?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

For an analogy, like the media-queries in CSS.
I am trying to find an event that gets fired on changing the size of the window.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't have to do anything when the window resizes. Assuming you're using `pack`, and `grid` properly, tkinter will automatically resize everything for you. Can you explain (preferably with a [mcve]) what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am making a tool to develop HTML, CSS, JavaScript (maybe we can call it pseudo-IDE?). I have included a webdriver section. When the user hits CTRL+S, the driver will be refreshed, thus rendering the newly entered code. I wanted to dock both the windows(the browser window and that tools window) in one screen together. So, at that time, some widgets have to be removed and the placing of others have to be re-layed. Thus, the question. (consider it like a 'Responsive-Software')

Comment: It's very easy to make a responsive UI without having to have any special code that triggers on a window resize.

Comment: Tell me about it please. Just raw overview will do.

Comment: The raw overview is to use the pack options `fill` , `side`, and `expand`, and/or the grid options `sticky`, as well as `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` to give rows and columns weight. Which ones you use, and how you use them, depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Since your question doesn't show what sort of layout you're trying to create, it's impossible to give a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're interested in `configure`. This, as you've described, is an event which is called when the root window is resized.

You can utilize this by binding to it, i.e. call a function when the window is resized.
This would look like `root.bind("<Configure>", resize)`, where `resize` is your function to deal with this.

In this case, `resize` would be passed the new windows `event`, which contains the new width and height of the window (by using `event.width` and `event.height`).

This is described with other events and bindings [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).